# In Fancybox Can I use the thumbnail helper for media files

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I would like to use fancy box to open various .mov files on a page, and want to have thumbnails to indicate that there are other videos. Is there a way to do this, I keep getting a spinning wheel.

Thanks
Becca

Comment: I think (most) .mov files are not optimal for streaming and you may have to wait for the full file to download before it starts playing (hence the spinning wheel) ... any chance you can convert them to mp4? If so, you may be interested in http://www.picssel.com/play-mp4-videos-with-mediaelement-js-in-fancybox/ .... and answering your question, yes you could use the thumbnail helper with videos, however I would recommend you to use a different source for the thumbnail.

Comment: Thanks @JFK! I actually did get it to work using " class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" data-caption=" " data-thumbnail="withtheth.jpg"  It is working great in chrome and safari, but now just is spinning in Firefox, I will try to put it up on jsfiddle to show how I got it to work.